# why VueJs router savedPosition for scrollBehavior returns first undefined and next {x:0,y:0}

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I use `vue-router 2.5.3`  and have two pages: first for long list (loaded via ajax) and second for details.

When I scroll down on list page and next navigate using  clicking back the browser button the browser always scrolls to the top. The value of `savedPosition` is for the first time `undefined` and for next attempts `Object {x: 0, y: 0}`

```
<div class="main-content">
  <router-view ></router-view>
</div>

scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    console.info(savedPosition) // first attemp undefined and next  always {x: 0, y: 0} regardless previous position

    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition
    } else if (to.name == from.name) 
    {
      return
    }
    else {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
    }
  },
  mode: 'history',
```

what is savedPosition and how it is triggered ?

Comment: So you don't have page transitions. Do you have position absolute/fixed with overflow-y: scroll? If yes, that's why it gets 0-0.

Comment: @Luna I use html/css template based on the https://vuematerial.github.io/#/ui-elements/layout - I don't see there usage of postion: absolute/fixed or overflow-y:scroll

Comment: thats weird. could you please do a JsFiddle or share a github repo?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?