# Vue-router scrollBehavior: Why is savedPosition always equal to { x: 0, y: 0 }?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I've seen several questions here on SO that are related to my issue, but none of them are identical, and their solutions do not work for me or they are unanswered (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011979/why-vuejs-router-savedposition-for-scrollbehavior-returns-first-undefined-and-ne).

I'm working on a Vue.js application that includes a list page. When the user clicks on one of the items in the list, the router navigates to a new 'detail page'. Then, when the user goes back (either through the browser buttons, or through a link on the page using `window.history.back()`, I'm using the `scrollBehavior` property of the router to bring the user back to their original position:

```
scrollBehavior: (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition;
  };
  return { x: 0, y: 0 };
};
```

Unfortunately, when the user navigates to the detail page, the page jumps back to the top of the window *before* navigating to the detail page component, and then, when the user returns to the list page, `savedPosition` is equal to `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`, meaning the user isn't returned to their original position.

Is there a way to have vue-router retain the position of the list page component? Is this related to the fact that the page jumps to the top right before navigating to the detail page component?

If any additional info is required, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Goodmorning,

I was struggling myself with the same issue for a while, where I have some overview pages with news cases for example. And when you click on a news item you will be navigated to the detailpage (to the top), but when you navigate back you end up somewhere else on the overview page. Also didn't find any solution yet and your question was almost the same as my case, especially: "meaning the user isn't returned to their original position."

I just got it to work with adding 'keep-alive' around my 'router-view'. Maybe this could also work in your case. My code in my App.vue file is now:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <the-header/>

    <keep-alive><router-view/></keep-alive>

    <the-footer/>

    <back-to-top/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  //import 'bulma'

  import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader'
  import TheFooter from './components/TheFooter'
  import BackToTop from './components/BackToTop'
  import VueMarkdown from 'vue-markdown'

  export default {
    components: {
      TheHeader,
      TheFooter,
      BackToTop,
      VueMarkdown
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import "assets/global.styles";
</style>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. We eventually decided on a workaround where we store the scroll position in localstorage, as we weren't able to come up with a solution. But thanks for your answer, I'm sure it'll help someone here. :)

Comment: @Niek bad practice